# Is there an FPTAS for 3-way number partitioning?

Tags: algorithms, approximation, polynomial-time, partitions, subset-sum

The maximization problem of the 3-way number partitioning reads as follows:
given $n$ positive integers, partition them into 3 subsets such that the smallest sum is as large as possible. It is known to be NP-hard, but does it have an FPTAS?

I found answers for some related problems:

- There is no FPTAS for MSSP (Multiple Subset Sum Problem) unless P=NP - https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S1052623498348481?journalCode=sjope8
- There is an FPTAS for 2-way number partitioning - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000003000060
- There is no FPTAS for 3-partition, since it is strongly NP-hard - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem
- There is a PTAS for 3-way number partitioning - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning

Is there any FPTAS for 3-way number partitioning?

Answer (score 2):

I found an FPTAS for a very similar problem: finding a partition such that the *largest* sum is as *small* as possible. This problem is equivalent to the problem of [identical-machines scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identical_machine_scheduling): there are $m$ identical machines (in our case $m=3$), and $n$ jobs with different processing times, and we need to assign jobs to machines such that the latest completion time is as early as possible. In this paper:

> Sartaj K. Sahni (1976). [Algorithms for Scheduling Independent Tasks](https://doi.org/10.1145/321921.321934). Journal of the ACM. 23 (1): 116–127.

there is an algorithm that attains at most $1+\epsilon$ of the minimum in time $O(n\cdot (n^2 / \epsilon)^{m-1})$, which is an FPTAS for any fixed $m$.

However, this does not answer the original problem, which is to make the *smallest* sum as *large* as possible.